# Number of neighboring points in a radius from a central point that are in the same depth range?

Tags: r

I have an issue I can't figure out. Say for example I have a set of data where each point has Latitudes, Longitudes, and depths. I need to create a script that could tell me the number of neighboring points that are in the same depth range as a central selected point.. I have a script that tells me how many neighboring points there are in the 2-d plane, but now I need to know which of those neighboring points are actually in the same zone as the 'Central point' it is being compared to. Any ideas or scripts would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please include the code you have so far, and some sample data (use `dput`)

Comment: A little piece of reproducible example would help, but you are probably looking for some intersections with buffer areas.